# curses initscr does not create window in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, curses

I am running Windows 7 with Python 2.7 and I installed the `curses` module with `pip` using the wheel file located at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses. I followed the basic instructions at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html for initializing `curses`; namely, from a Python command prompt,

```
import curses
stdscr=curses.initscr()
```

and nothing happens except that I am unable to type *anything* more in the command window and I have to close it, although it appears no actual error has occurred. The cursor continues blinking as though awaiting input, but I'm unable to control it any more.

What am I doing wrong?

Copying and pasting from the console window below.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import curses
>>> stdscr=curses.initscr()
>>>
```

A screen seems to flash on but immediately disappears and the console becomes useless (although as mentioned the cursor continues blinking... it is not "unresponsive" in the typical sense. It just doesn't respond to keyboard input.).

Comment: nothing ... that is the initialized screen ... what you need to do is read some tutorials on it :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley That's exactly what I was doing. The howto link above is the first thing that comes up when I google "tutorial on curses python". If I haven't been clear, the DOS emulator does not respond at all to keyboard input when I've run the commands above. Is that the correct behavior?

Comment: I seem to remember that being the case (Its been quite a while since i messed with curses ... ) although I just tried to install the whl and it didnt work as I expected... curses is a real pain I would recommend a real gui framework instead tbh

Comment: @eryksun Thanks. I corrected the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do much that is useful with the curses package in an interactive command-line shell as shown in the question, because the curses package initializes the input to a raw mode (or equivalent on Windows) so that it can capture individual keys.

The command-line shell uses line-buffering, and given the change of input mode, it will not get lines.

Rather, you will get best results by running a complete script - which would call `getch` or `getstr` to read input from the terminal window.

Comment: it may take more than that ... I tried to get a minimum example working on windows and failed (granted I didnt spend long on it) I think @eryksun's comment on the OP is close to the mark

Comment: @eryksun is clarifying that the environment must be a console window rather than MS-DOS (some people still think that a console window is "DOS").  The significant feature about the OP's comments is the problem with keyboard input after a flashing of the window.